# Use Group By against two separate columns in SQL to compute a new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table called **transactions** which looks as follows:

```
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------|
|order_id |customer_name |  brand_name  |   order_time_stamp       | 
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------|
|   1     | Jack         |  Pepsi       | 2019-02-23 20:02:21.550. |
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------|
|   2     | Dorothy      |  Fanta       | 2019-02-23 20:03:21.550. |
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------|
|   3     | Dorothy      |  Fanta       | 2019-02-23 20:04:21.550. |
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------|
|   4     | Jack         |  Fanta       | 2019-02-23 20:05:21.550. |
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------------------|
```

As is evident, this is a table that captures every order at an online store with the order_id being the primary key. What I am trying to capture is the number of additional orders grouped by brand_name as follows:

```
enter code here
|------------|--------------------|
| brand_name | additional orders  |
|------------|--------------------| 
| Pepsi      |         0          |
|------------|--------------------| 
| Fanta      |         1          | 
|------------|--------------------|
```

However, additional orders are defined on a customer level and are defined as the sum of all orders after the first order by a customer.

My strategy to do this was was to use the rank() function as follows:

```
select rank() over( partition by customer_name order by order_time_stamp) as rank
from transactions
```

This creates an additional column which creates a rank per customer. However, I am not sure how to now group this on a brand_level and get the output as I have shown

Comment: Why isn't "Fanta" 2 instead?  Both Jack and Dorothy have a second order with Fanta.

Comment: the additional order count is on a brand level..when Jack orders Fanta, it happens for the first time.

Comment: You guys need to team up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to rank the orders per customer, then filter on "additional" orders (that is, every order that whose rank is greater than 1), then aggregate by `brand_name`:

```
select brand_name, count(*) no_additional_orders
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by customer_name order by order_time_stamp) rn
    from transactions t
) t
where rn > 1
group by brand_name
```

If you want to also take in account brands that have no additional order, then you can move the filtering logic to the aggregate function:

```
select brand_name, sum(rn > 1) no_additional_orders
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by customer_name order by order_time_stamp) rn
    from transactions t
) t
group by brand_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is rather confusing.  I think you want everything after the earliest timestamp, not the earliest order.  This is a subtle difference, but important:

```
select brand_name,
       sum(order_time_stamp > min_ots)
from (select t.*, min(order_time_stamp) over (partition by customer_name) as min_ots
      from t
     ) t
group by brand_name;
```

You can do something similar with `rank()` as well:

```
select brand_name,
       sum(seqnum > 1)
from (select t.*, 
             rank() over (partition by customer_name order by order_time_stamp) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by brand_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sum all the orders of each `customer_name` per `brand_name` except 1, because you don't want in the sum each customer's 1st order.
You can do it with by subtracting from the total number of orders the number of distinct customers that ordered the product which is equal to the number of 1st orders of each customer:

```
select brand_name, 
       count(*) - count(distinct customer_name) additional_orders
from transactions
group by brand_name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=80209632c4d9832b8eccc1492eaea0f6).
Results:

```
> brand_name | additional_orders
> :--------- | ----------------:
> Pepsi      |                 0
> Fanta      |                 1
```